# Fragment must be a public static class to be properly recreated from instance state

Tags: android, fragment

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXQKU.png)
this is error info

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hkmedical.hkmedical/com.hkmedical.hkmedical.pdf.DocumentActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.hkmedical.hkmedical.pdf.DocumentActivity.PlaceholderFragment must be a public static class to be  properly recreated from instance state.
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2444)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2504)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:165)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:682)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.hkmedical.hkmedical.pdf.DocumentActivity.PlaceholderFragment must be a public static class to be  properly recreated from instance state.
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:384)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:369)
                                                                         at com.hkmedical.hkmedical.pdf.DocumentActivity.onCreate(DocumentActivity.java:55)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6367)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2397)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2504) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:165) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:682) 


in  the activity, when onCreate, the runtime exception appeared.
 fragment = new PlaceholderFragment(this);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    }
```

here is zhe inner fragment

```
 @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    private Context mContext;

    public PlaceholderFragment(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = new View(mContext);
        rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        mDoc = new SPDocument();
        long lResult = mDoc.open(mFilePath);
        if (lResult == 0) {
            drawView();
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    public void drawView() {
        mReaderView = new SPReaderViews(mContext, mDoc);
        mView = mReaderView.showDocument();
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        getActivity().addContentView(mReaderView, params);
        mView.goToPage(0);}
```

this is my gradle:

```
 compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
```

i want to know how to make it work well,i want to know how to make it work well,i want to know how to make it work well.
but zhe code works well in my other project.

i want to know how to make it work well,i want to know how to make it work well,i want to know how to make it work well.
but zhe code works well in my other project.

i want to know how to make it work well,i want to know how to make it work well,i want to know how to make it work well.
but zhe code works well in my other project.

Comment: change " add " to " replace "

Comment: Fragment should have only empty constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that fragments should have an empty constructor. If your application will be killed by Android system and you open it again Android will try to restore the last state of activities and fragments. In this case, it will use default constructor so all stuff that you pass to the constructor will be lost. If you need pass data to fragment, you should use `fragment.setArguments()`. If you need to get context in fragment you can use `getActivity()` or `getContext()`